# Tabbed Gallery Image Hover, Control.Tabs: Help?

Tags: javascript, image, prototype, tabs, gallery

**I'm struggling on how my attempt at this tutorial is not working for me?**

http://livepipe.net/control/tabs

**Here is my attempt:**

http://www.visually-minded.com/portfolio-v2.php

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it!

Thanks

Dave

Comment: You tagged it as jQuery but this is a Prototype tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the libarary. Download it [here](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and include it in  your document.

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking this question as answered. Thanks!